# How to turn off https security risk related messages on ASP.NET MVC page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-2, session-timeout

We have a secured website using ASP.NET MVC Framework.
The User session timeout is implemented using **JQuery IDLETIMEOUT** plugin.

So that If the session timeout is set for 30 min, it displays a message "**You are about to be Signedout due to inactivity**" with "**Stay Logged on**". This popup Message displays for last 30 sec and if the user clicks on this message, the session continues, else this message disappears and User is Logged out.

Now I noticed once security warning message that is displaying from the Internet Explorer "**This page is accessing the information that is not under its control. This poses a security Risk. Do you want to continue?**"

I am wondering how to get rid of this secury warning message. This warning message is coming along with the About to session timeout message.

Here is the JQuery code that i used for session Timeout:

```
 <% if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {%>
         $(document).idleTimeout({
            inactivity: 30 * MIN,
            noconfirm : 30 * SEC,
            redirect_url: '/Account/SessionOut',
            sessionAlive: 0, // 30000, //10 Minutes
            click_reset: true,
            alive_url: '',
            logout_url: '/Account/SessionOut'
            });
        <%} %>
```

Comment: What's the code that displays the warning message? It seems likely that there is something in the message box that's fetching a resource (eg. an image, stylesheet, background image, script?) from an `http://` URL.

Answer (score 3):

This warning comes when your page is accessing URL that are non-secure. That is a https page while loading is giving hit to http urls debug along these lines to find out a solution